# Is it bad class design to have deferred initialization of complex class?

Tags: c++, initialization, raii

I know RAII and was trying to stick to single step instantiation. As long as all arguments for members are given, instance is valid, and it destruct at destructor.

However, if the class is big enough to store multiple structs, constructor soon have too many arguments. Also, if a class has dependent instantiation such as LoadFromXXX or InitializeFromXXX type of function, having 2 step instantiation seems the best option to me. Especially, if the class instance is member of other class (not as pointer), constructor chain begins and all constructor arguments must be obtained. In other words, it is difficult to insert such operation as

```
Instance.LoadConfig(FilePath);
Instance.Create();
```

To me, it seems good workaround to cope with too many argument situation and delayed instantiation by applying somewhat similar to that of builder, while losing single step RAII. Release issue can be managed in destructor using if.

```
if (pAllocated)
    delete pAllocated;

Or pAllocated->Release();
```

The only problem i can think of this method is that this opens partially valid instance or empty instance.

Is this unacceptably bad?

Comment: I have never heard of RAII sticking to single step instantiation.  I made a change to some code yesterday, that now has initialization at first use.  The initialization is not small but not huge either.  Sometimes, there is no method to avoid a lot of initialization code.

Comment: Oh really? I saw somewhere like "is init or 2 step initialization bad?" Kind of question saying having two step initialization breaks RAII.

Comment: In the embedded systems world, some initializations like USB or SPI Bus, have more than 5 statements to perform initialization.  Also, if you have composition, the members need initialization also, which increases execution time and expands the code size.

Comment: You always have other options. For example, you could create a config loader class and pass a loader object into a constructor of `Instance`. Just splitting initialization into several public functions and forcing a user to call these functions in particular order doesn't look like a good design.

Comment: @Thomas Does it mean that having 2 step initialization (not constructor having all initialization with huge arguments) still belongs to RAII? Just having delayed instantiation feature? Is it acceptable design?

Comment: @Evg yes that was the option for maintaining single step RAII. Create other class for config data and pass it to Instance constructor. This requires 1 more class to write, I was worried if  keep adding class might hurt simplicity part of RAII. But that is possible too.

Comment: So the cpp core guidelines suggest: [A constructor should create a fully initialized object](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c41-a-constructor-should-create-a-fully-initialized-object)

Comment: Avoid deferring initialization unless avoiding results in worse code. I generally recommend going out of your way to do all of the initialization in the constructor, but at some point you have to throw in the towel.

Comment: The 2 step initialization is some kind of guide that somebody came up with so that people would not put unnecessary code in the initialization.  Sometimes, you only put in code for initialization, stand back and see how big the initialization is.  IMHO, a complete and accurate initialization, regardless of the LOC, is better than a complicated initialization limited to 2 steps only (lots of things require more than 2 steps).  If you can get away with an empty constructor, then do so; all operations should call the initialization function (which performs init. once).

Comment: The issue with "multistep initialization" or similar is that all the copy/move ctors, assignment operators, and destructor need to be aware of all the steps and be prepared to deal with objects at any intermediate step properly.

Comment: Sometimes you have no choice but to instantiate an object before all the data needed to initialize it is available. You just have to build in some bumper rails so that it won't do uninitialized stuff until initialization is completed.

Comment: "Deferred initialization" is often considered a very bad idea, since it is a ready opportunity to either forget to initialise an object or check if it is initialised before the object is used by any code that assumes (or relies on) it being correctly initialised - which can cause major consequences (up to and including undefined behaviour). Initialisation in a constructor is considered preferable, since *creation of the object* can be deferred as needed in C++ (e.g. until all data needed to initialise is obtained) and the *compiler* can detect invalid usage.